# Cakephp 2 multiple DBs

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I want to switch DB based on domain, selecting credentials from another DB, but I can't switch..

**AppController.php**

```
// Select username, password and database based on domain
$this->Company->find('first', [...]);

if ($company) {
    // Connect to second database, droping connection from first.
    $dataSource = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');
    $dataSource->config['login'] = $company['Company']['dbuser'];
    $dataSource->config['password'] = $company['Company']['dbpass'];
    $dataSource->config['database'] = $company['Company']['dbname'];

    /**
     * PROBLEM START HERE:
     * Here, need to use new database settings, and, this case
     * Company table does not exists, but I always get it, so,
     * I think I am connected with the first and not second connection.
     */
    print_r($this->Company->find('first'));
}
```

How I can correct this?

**EDIT**

I have tried without success:

```
ConnectionManager::drop('default');
ConnectionManager::create('default', $settings);
```

A `print_r(ConnectionManager::create('default', $settings))` return:

```
[... lots of things ... ]
[config] => Array
    (
        [persistent] => 
        [host] => localhost
        [login] => login
        [password] => password
        [database] => database
        [port] => 3306
        [datasource] => Database/Mysql
        [prefix] => 
    )
[... more things ... ]
```

**EDIT 2**

Now, I can switch database, but, Company Model always get the old database settings.

**FooController.php**

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class FooController extends AppController {
    var $uses = array('Foo', 'Company');

    public function index() {
        echo'<pre>';
        print_r($this->Company->find('first')); // Here I get from old settings
        print_r($this->Foo->find('first')); // Here I gete from new settings
        echo'</pre>';

        $this->layout = false;
        $this->render(false);
    }
}
```

**AppController.php**

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    $company = ClassRegistry::init('Company')->find('first');
    $settings = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => $company['Company']['dbuser'],
        'password' => $company['Company']['dbpass'],
        'database' => $company['Company']['dbname'],
        'prefix' => ''
    );

    ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default')->disconnect();

    ConnectionManager::drop('default');
    ConnectionManager::create('default', $settings);

    ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default')->connect();
}
```

Comment: Can you check the details on `$dataSource`? It might have something there still linking to the old connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to dynamically create a config and change configs on-the-fly. I don't know if this will work, but it may lead you to the answer.

First we need to create a config for the datasource to use. For this we can use [ConnectionManager::create](http://api.cakephp.org/view_source/Connection-Manager#l-195)

Next, we need to change configs on-the-fly and for that we can use [Model::setDataSource](http://api.cakephp.org/view_source/model#line-3152)

I haven't tried, but it looks like it *should* do. If there are issues, leave a comment so I can update the answer.

Edit: This may not work since every model would need to change the to the new datasource. There is a `ConnectionManager::drop()` method that you could use to drop the `default` config and then `ConnectionManager::create('default', array(...));` to use a new default perhaps.

Comment: I have droped and made a new default datasource, but, I cant get what I want.

Comment: Try `ConnectionManager::getDataSource()->reconnect();` afterwards. Or ->disconnect(); first and then change datasource setting and then ->connect();

Comment: Now, I can connect the first and second database. If I have `company` table in both database, I allways get results from the wrong database (default connection before dataSource changes)..

Comment: Not sure at this point. When doing find calls the model uses `$this->getDataSource();` which returns `ConnectionManager::getDataSource($this->useDbConfig);` `$this->useDbConfig` should use 'default' that we've changed to.

Comment: Yep, but, I can't find why this not occour.

Comment: Are you doing this with debug turned "on"? Any error showing up? A tip, if you have models that don't exist on all databases, you will have to `unbind()` them when they are not needed to avoid errors.

Comment: Yep, debug on, without errors. I have not unbinded any model. Will try tonight your suggestion.

Comment: Can you explain what is the `unbind()` (you mean `unbindModel()`?) ?

Comment: Only the model `Company` does not work. Others models, if I have same tables from different connections, I get the correct table.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. How did you manage to solve that? I've already tried to drop the connection, but Cakephp is still using the default connection...

Comment: I'm trying to use the SetDataSource, I already created connections with: ConnectionManager::create(); And later I tried $this->Model->setDataSource('database_wanted'); But stills getting from default. What should I do ? Because later I'll need to use the default connection again. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can switch databases in your database config file.

Configure your Config/database.php file as follows:

```
<?php
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

    // config for e.g. localhost
    public $default = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => 'root',
        'password' => 'xxxxx',
        'database' => 'cake',
        'encoding' => 'utf8'
    );

    // DB config specifically for your domain
    public $domain_x = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => 'username_at_hosting_provider',
        'password' => '087bJ#ytvh&^YU#T',
        'database' => 'blabla_cake',
        'encoding' => 'utf8'
    );

    public function __construct(){
        // switch config depending on domain / env('HTTP_HOST')
        if(env('HTTP_HOST')=='domain_x.com'){
            $this->default = $this->domain_x;
        }
        // otherwise keep $this->default
    }
}
```

### Edit:

It seems a was a bit too fast answering your question: it does not really cover your question. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I managed to fix this problem creating the `__construct` function whithin AppModel and put all the code to drop the default datasource and create another with the new config. Something like this:

AppModel.php

```
public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null)
{
    App::uses('CakeSession', 'Model/Datasource');

    parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);

    if ($this->useDbConfig == 'default') {
        // Change the datasource config
        $user = CakeSession::read('Auth.User');
        $this->changeDataSource($user);
    }
}



public function changeDataSource($config)
{ 
    ...
    ...
    ...
    $dados = array();
    $dados['database']   = $config['titulo_bd'];
    $dados['host']       = $config['host_bd'];
    $dados['login']      = $config['login_bd'];
    $dados['password']   = $config['senha_bd'];
    $dados['datasource'] = 'Database/Mysql';
    $dados['persistent'] = false;
    $dados['prefix']     = '';
    $dados['encoding']   = 'utf8';


    ConnectionManager::create('default', $dados);
    ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default')->connect();
}
```

Comment: Hey! Why you store sensitive data into user's session?

Comment: That's true. I just wanted to fix this annoying problem and forget about this. What do you suggest?

Comment: I solved this with a table storing database data (see Security::rijndael to store passwords securely).

Answer (score 0):

My case is very similar. In my case, I have two types of connections. One is the default core connection which uses the Config/database.php file for connection configurations. Second one is a dynamic configuration which uses db details saved for logged in user. So, for a few specific actions I have to switch between the default db connection and user based db connection. Here's how it came up.

To switch to user based db connection from default file

```
try {
  ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default')->disconnect();
  ConnectionManager::drop('default');
  ConnectionManager::create('default', $this->config);
  ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default')->connect();
  $db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');
} catch (MissingDatabaseException $e) {
  $this->Session->setFlash($e->getMessage()); 
}
```

where $this->config is user based connection.

To switch back to default file based connection I do:

```
try {
  ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default')->disconnect();
  ConnectionManager::drop('default');
  $dbconfig = new DATABASE_CONFIG();
  ConnectionManager::create('default', $dbconfig->default);
  ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default')->connect();
  $db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');
}
```

where $dbconfig->default i.e. $default contains my default connection configuration in Config/database.php