# How to set database.config infos using an consult from database postgres on CakePHP?

Tags: php, database, postgresql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I want to set the database config from CakePhP 2.x with data from database

Example - database.config:

```
public $bd_test = array (
        'datasource' => 'Database/Postgres',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => 'root',
        'password' => 'root',
        'database' => 'bd_test',
        'port' => '5432',
        //'encoding' => 'UTF-8'
);
```

Should looks like:

`$dataFromDb = $this->Model->find('all', array('fields' => array('host', 'login', 'password', 'database', 'port'), 'conditions' => array('database' => 'bd_test')));`

```
public $bd_test = array (
        'datasource' => 'Database/Postgres',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => $dataFromDb['host'],
        'login' => $dataFromDb['login'],
        'password' => $dataFromDb['password'],
        'database' => $dataFromDb['database'],
        'port' => '5432',
        //'encoding' => 'UTF-8'
);
```

Something like that.. I guess that the Idea is clear, right? If need some more information, please tell me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set config-datasets at runtime with `Configure::write('nameofconfigfield,'value');`
If this does'nt work, I'm sorry. I'm not familiar with CakePHP 2.x, I only used 3.x.

I answered like I understood your question.
But I don't know what you want to achieve with changing the DB connection at runtime.

Comment: I want to get those infos (host, database, port.... ) making an consult directly on database. ( Keep the database configuration on database ) . I want to retrieve the data that contains the information of database.config. Understand now ?

Comment: I think I see it. In CakePHP 2.x the DB config is not in the core configuration file right?

Comment: CakePHP 2.x keeps the configuration in App/Config/Database.config

Comment: Can you edit the config file with the method from my answer above?

Comment: Something like this ? Configure::write('host', 'localhost'); ? Off-topic: Can you tell me if ConnectionManager::create() method creates just a temporary connection ?

Comment: Ok, sorry but the Configure::write() method you can't use because this is only for the core configuration file. 
As i understand the documentation, you can create a new Connection with the ConnectionManager class and this Connection should be stored in the  database.config file.
I've found an other stackoverflow question under this link [Other Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11942189/cakephp-2-multiple-dbs). Read the accepted answer I think this shoul solve your problem.

Comment: I'm already doing like this... The problem is: Still getting the default configuration. But yes,  It's something like that , that I want. hehe

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add your current code, so i can help better i think. :D

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
 public function beforeFilter(){        
    App::uses('ConnectionManager', 'Model');
    $databases = $this->YourModel->find('all');
    foreach($databases as $valor){
        foreach($valor as $value){
            $settings = array(
                    'datasource' => 'Database/Postgres',
                    'persistent' => false,
                    'host' => $value['host'],
                    'login' => $value['user'],
                    'password' => $value['password'],
                    'database' => $value['database'],
                    'port' => $value['port']
            );
            ConnectionManager::create($value['nome_banco'], $settings);
        }
    }
}
```

And Later I had to do `setDataSource` or you can replace the default connection with : ConnectionManager::create('default', $settings);
Right this:

```
ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default')->disconnect();
ConnectionManager::drop('default');
ConnectionManager::create('default', $settings);
```

But how I want to use both connections I didn't that. Thanks to M4R1KU that helped me.